# ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Tags: python

I'm using Pandas 0.20.3 in my python 3.X. I want to add one column in a pandas data frame from another pandas data frame. Both the data frame contains 51 rows. So I used following code:

```
class_df['phone']=group['phone'].values
```

I got following error message:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

class_df.dtypes gives me:

```
Group_ID         object
YEAR             object
Terget           object
phone            object
age              object
```

and `type(group['phone'])` returns `pandas.core.series.Series`

Can you suggest me what changes I need to do to remove this error?

The first 5 rows of group['phone'] are given below:

```
0    [735015372, 72151508105, 7217511580, 721150431...
1                                                   []
2    [735152771, 7351515043, 7115380870, 7115427...
3    [7111332015, 73140214, 737443075, 7110815115...
4    [718218718, 718221342, 73551401, 71811507...
Name: phoen, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a column of ragged lists. Your only option is to assign a list of lists, and not an *array* of lists (which is what `.value` gives).

```
class_df['phone'] = group['phone'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 60):

In most cases, this error comes when you return an empty dataframe. The best approach that worked for me was to check if the dataframe is empty first before using apply()

```py
if len(df) !=  0:
    df['indicator'] = df.apply(assign_indicator, axis=1)
```

Comment: Solved my day you are a genius

Comment: Another common way to check if the dataframe is not empty is: `if not df.empty:`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an if-statement, you can use set `result_type` argument of *apply()* function to "reduce".

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(func, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer for most users because you don't need the conditional blocks and indentation the if-statements approach requires.

Answer (score 7):

The error of the Question-Headline

"ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series"

might as well occur if for what ever reason the table does not have any rows.

Answer (score 2):

The data assigned to a column in the DataFrame must be a single dimension array. For example, consider a num_arr to be added to a DataFrame

```
num_arr.shape
```

> (1, 126)

For this num_arr to be added to a DataFrame `column`, It should be reshaped....

```
num_arr = num_arr.reshape(-1, )
num_arr.shape
```

> (126,)

Now I could set this arr as a DataFrame column

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['numbers'] = num_arr
```